# SQL composite primary key

Tags: sql

I've been trying the whole afternoon to make this work but it gives me an error when creating the 2nd, 3rd and 4th table (those with the foreign keys referencing the composite primary key on the first table). It says there are no PKs on the referenced table. I've googled, checked stackoverflow, checked my notes and still don't know why it gives me the error.

Sorry the code is in Spanish and thanks in advance

```
create database proyecto_camiones
go
use proyecto_camiones
go

create table servicios (
    ruta int not null,
    nif varchar(9) not null,
    matricula varchar (10) not null,
    fecha date not null
    primary key (ruta, nif, matricula)
    )

create table camiones (
    matricula varchar(10) not null unique references servicios (matricula),
    fecha_alta date not null,
    ultima_inspeccion date not null
    )

create table transportistas (
    nif varchar(9) not null references servicios (nif),
    nombre varchar(30) not null,
    direccion varchar(30) not null,
    fecha_nac date not null
    )

create table rutas (
    codigo int not null unique references servicios (ruta),
    inicio varchar(15) not null,
    final varchar(15) not null
    )
```

Comment: The foreign key must consist of 3 columns, so as to match the ones of the primary key.

Comment: so basically I cannot form a Composite PK from columns belonging to different tables? I mean, they all must belong to the same table? thanks

Comment: Yes, you have to include *all columns* of the PK in the  referencing table.

Comment: I expanded my comment to an answer. (Also, the poster is always notified of a comment but if there is more than one  other commenter then one must use @ for one of them to get notified. Also, "thanks" comments are discouraged.)

Answer (score 1):

Since it is composite primary key you have to use all columns included in PK.
For  `camiones` table it looks like

```
create table servicios (
    ruta int not null,
    nif varchar(9) not null,
    matricula varchar (10) not null,
    fecha date not null
    primary key (ruta, nif, matricula)
    )

create table camiones (
    ruta int not null,
    nif varchar(9) not null,
    matricula varchar (10) not null,
    fecha_alta date not null,
    ultima_inspeccion date not null,
    primary key (ruta, nif, matricula),
    FOREIGN KEY (ruta, nif, matricula) REFERENCES servicios(ruta, nif, matricula)
    )
```

But if you don't want to store redundad columns (`nif`, `matricula`) you can change PK to one separate column `id` as below

```
create table servicios (
    id int,
    ruta int not null,
    nif varchar(9) not null,
    matricula varchar (10) not null,
    fecha date not null
    primary key (id)
    )

create table camiones (
    ruta int not null,
    nif varchar(9) not null,
    matricula varchar (10) not null,
    fecha_alta date not null,
    ultima_inspeccion date not null,
    idservicios int,
    primary key (ruta),
    FOREIGN KEY (idservicios) REFERENCES servicios(id)
    )
```

Comment: so basically I cannot form a Composite PK from columns belonging to different tables? I mean, they all must belong to the same table? thanks

Comment: @ArturAlvaro No, you can't.

Comment: See my comment to the question: it's a composite FK not PK that must reference a single table.

Answer (score 0):

One can form a composite (super)key (UNIQUE NOT NULL or PRIMARY KEY) from a list of columns "belonging to different tables" (poor phrasing) regardless of any FKs (foreign keys) that any of them participate in. But a composite FK must reference a column list declared as a composite (super)key in a table. So the error is because your REFERENCES target tables and columns do not have corresponding superkeys declared.

So possibly you want codigo, nif, matricula in every base table and the foreign keys to be

```
FOREIGN KEY (codigo, nif, matricula)
    REFERENCES servicios(ruta, nif, matricula)
```

More likely you want servicios ruta, nif and matricula values to always be present as values in the corresponding columns of the other three tables. (Ie your FK declarations are in the wrong direction.)

```
create table servicios (
    ruta int not null,
    nif varchar(9) not null,
    matricula varchar (10) not null,
    fecha date not null
    primary key (ruta, nif, matricula),
    foreign key (ruta) references rutas (codigo),
    foreign key (nif) references transportistas (nif),
    foreign key (matricula) references camiones (matricula)
    )

create table camiones (
    matricula varchar(10) primary key,
    fecha_alta date not null,
    ultima_inspeccion date not null
    )

create table transportistas (
    nif varchar(9) primary key,
    nombre varchar(30) not null,
    direccion varchar(30) not null,
    fecha_nac date not null
    )

create table rutas (
    codigo int primary key,
    inicio varchar(15) not null,
    final varchar(15) not null
    )
```

But since you haven't given the meaning of your bases or even an example query with input and output and you acknowledge that your code is wrong we can only guess what right is.